# How do I make my login form be the top most while on a separate thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, topmost

I currently have a login form that is launched in a separate thread when the main application launches. I tried setting the TopMost property on the login form but it still does not work. I don't want to use the Application.Run method since I am dealing with several types of login forms and I just create an interface. The code below has been simplified:

**UPDATE: This was the way the Login window was designed. I cannot change this. This worked in Windows XP, but does not work in Windows 7.**

```
private void FormLoad()
{
  ParameterizedThreadStart threadStart = delegate {
                                 BeginLogin(_loginResults);
                                 };
  var thread = new Thread(threadStart);
  thread.Start();
}

private void BeginLogin(LoginResults callback)
{
  LoginData loginData = GetLoginData();

  if (callback != null)
    callback(loginData);
}

private LoginData GetLoginData()
{
  ILoginForm loginForm = LoginFormCreate();
  loginForm.TopMostDialog = true;  // This property sets the TopMost property.

  return loginForm.ShowLoginDialog();
}
```

Comment: Why would you run the login form on a different thread in the first place ?

Comment: The login process takes a while. We don't want to prevent the user from doing work in other areas of the application where we don't need to do the log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing you should then use Pinvoke. You can do it with [ShowWindow](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ShowWindow.html).

And it can be done also with [SetWindowLong](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/03/24/95259.aspx).

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for this. The SetWindowLong seems to be working most of the time. I'm currently playing with this right now.

Answer (score 2):

Using a thread is the cause of the problem.  The login window is entirely separated from the main window, it doesn't get disabled by ShowDialog().  And the main thread keeps motoring so all the user has to do is move the login window off to the side to use the main window.

Just don't use a thread, call ShowDialog() directly.

Comment: This was the way the Login window was designed. I cannot change this. This worked in Windows XP, but does not work in Windows 7.

Comment: This is a site for programmers.  We change things.  Best place to find help with a Win7 compatibility problem is superuser.com